How do I add an extra property to some implemented classes but not others
I have some existing code that I need to modify.
public class DataResults {
    // lots of properties and methods

    public static implicit operator string(DataResults result) {
    }

    public override string ToString() {
    }
}

public interface IPerformProcessing {
    // other defs

    DataResults result(); 
}

public class Class1 : IPerformProcessing {
    public DataResults result() {
    }
}

public class Class2 : IPerformProcessing {
    public DataResults result() {
    }
}

// plus numerous other classes that implement IPerformProcessing

I now need to modify some of the classes that implement IPerformProcessing so that DataResults contains 1 more property. How do I do this? Please help
I think I have to do something like:
    public interface IPerformProcessing<T> where T : IDataResults 
    {
        IDataResults result();
    }

but now I am stuck

To be clear: when you say "so that DataResults contains 1 more property", do you actually mean something else?  Because if you mean that 'as written', you could just add another property to DataResults, and no modifications to IPerformProcessing are required.  Or is it the case that the concrete class DataResults cannot be modified?

If you want to re-factor the DataResults to introduce a "base" shared interface but allow for more flexibility for specific implementations you're close:
public interface IPerformProcessing<T> where T : IDataResults 
{
    T result();
}

... would likely be what you are looking for. This allows your Processing implementations to nominate a specific concrete implementation of the DataResult to suit them.
public class Class1 : IPerformProcessing<DataResults1> {
    public DataResults1 result() {
    }
}

public class Class2 : IPerformProcessing<DataResults2> {
    public DataResults2 result() {
    }
}

Obviously with meaningful names for the data results. The results type can be shared between multiple processing classes if they use the same  result structure, or you can personalize the concrete types for individual tests.
This would best involve a re-factoring of the existing DataResult as your comment "lots of properties and methods" smells of a bunch of null-able details that apply to specific implementations. Separate these into more purposeful concrete data results that can share a base interface or base class for values that all share.
